# What are 'quick cook' beans?

Tags: food-preservation, beans

I've been looking at recipes to prepare in bulk and store in mason jars for a few weeks. A company called Honeyville Farms sells a bunch of freeze dried stuff for this purpose, as well as 'quick cook' beans in different varieties.  They claim that the beans are dry, but can be fully cooked in 20 minutes.  Sounds great, but they are also quite expensive.  Are these actually cooked and then freeze dried beans?  If not, is is possible to prepare 'quick cook' beans myself without buying the expensive cans online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this video on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ft6g0WbvlzE), which is one of the few references I could find:

They are essentially fully cooked beans that have then been dehydrated for long term storage.  Therefore, they will "cook" again quickly as they are already cooked, and are essentially just being rehydrated.

If you listen to the video (it is mostly narration, and a few still pictures, and are very, very, very patient in listening), the narrator will describe how she creates them which comes down to:

1. Pre-soak the beans
2. Pressure cook them
3. Dehydrate them

Note that the first two steps are probably not that critical—you could cook the beans by whichever method you prefer.

Comment: Multiple windows was the key :-)